# Windows Phone 8 application won't start unless in debug mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I am in the finishing staging of creating my first Window Phone 8 application.  I am using MVVMCross as the MVVM framework for the application.  The application is running great in debug mode on both the simulator and my connected phone.  The issue I am having is the application will not run on my phone unless it's attached via debugging.  When I click on the application on the phone it simply flashes but never launches the application.

Some additional information after using Crittercism to catch the exception:

0  at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.ResolveTService

1  at Mobile.Contacts.Phone.App.b__0()

Answer (score 3):

After further review I realized that I had the following setup code inside 
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)

var setup = new Setup(RootFrame);
setup.Initialize();